# How to specify names of columns for x and y when joining in dplyr?

Tags: r, join, left-join, dplyr

I have two data frames that I want to join using dplyr. One is a data frame containing first names.

```
test_data <- data.frame(first_name = c("john", "bill", "madison", "abby", "zzz"),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The other data frame contains a cleaned up version of the Kantrowitz names corpus, identifying gender. Here is a minimal example:

```
kantrowitz <- structure(list(name = c("john", "bill", "madison", "abby", "thomas"), gender = c("M", "either", "M", "either", "M")), .Names = c("name", "gender"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I essentially want to look up the gender of the name from the `test_data` table using the `kantrowitz` table. Because I'm going to abstract this into a function `encode_gender`, I won't know the name of the column in the data set that's going to be used, and so I can't guarantee that it will be `name`, as in `kantrowitz$name`.

In base R I would perform the merge this way:

```
merge(test_data, kantrowitz, by.x = "first_names", by.y = "name", all.x = TRUE)
```

That returns the correct output:

```
  first_name gender
1       abby either
2       bill either
3       john      M
4    madison      M
5        zzz   <NA>
```

But I want to do this in dplyr because I'm using that package for all my other data manipulation. The dplyr `by` option to the various `*_join` functions only lets me specify one column name, but I need to specify two. I'm looking for something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
# either
left_join(test_data, kantrowitz, by.x = "first_name", by.y = "name")
# or
left_join(test_data, kantrowitz, by = c("first_name", "name"))
```

What is the way to perform this kind of join using dplyr?

(Never mind that the Kantrowitz corpus is a bad way to identify gender. I'm working on a better implementation, but I want to get this working first.)

Comment: You can't currently, but it's on the to do list: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/177

Answer (score 213, accepted):

This feature has been added in dplyr v0.3. You can now pass a named character vector to the `by` argument in `left_join` (and other joining functions) to specify which columns to join on in each data frame. With the example given in the original question, the code would be:

```
left_join(test_data, kantrowitz, by = c("first_name" = "name"))
```

Comment: **edit** This works in the general case as well :  `left_join(data_a, data_b, by = c("a.first" = "b.first", "a.second" = "b.second", "a.third" = "b.third"))` ?

Comment: The `by =` is optional. You can do `left_join(test_data, kantrowitz, c("first_name" = "name"))`

Comment: That's true of any argument to a function. But I generally find it better to be explicit by using named arguments rather than position matching in this case.

Comment: Some users may suggest updating the syntax to use join_by().
The following is the equivalent:
left_join(test_data, kantrowitz, by = join_by(first_name == name))

Answer (score 5):

This is more a workaround than a real solution. You can create a new object `test_data` with another column name:

```
left_join("names<-"(test_data, "name"), kantrowitz, by = "name")

     name gender
1    john      M
2    bill either
3 madison      M
4    abby either
5     zzz   <NA>
```

Comment: Renaming induces a copy, I think, which may be way dplyr avoids it and makes you do it instead.

Comment: In 0.1.2 you'll at least be able to do `select(test_data, first_name = name)` and that will only make a shallow copy.

Comment: Use `data.table::setnames`?

Comment: the solution select(test_data, first_name = name) does not work as of June 2014

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the function "[join_by()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html)"

```
inner_join(test_data, kantrowitz, by = join_by(first_name == name))
```

from dplyr.